# Help identifying a large FAQ about women pastors made by John Piper and someone else

Tags: reference-request, women, pastor, john-piper

I don't know if was a book, article, or interview, but recently I read a document which contained 30-50 question and answer items related to women as pastors. I know it was by John Piper and potentially co-written by another author or pastor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

John Piper and Wayne Grudham have published the following books which may deal with the subject of women as pastors:

> [Recovering Biblical Manhood and Womanhood](https://www.desiringgod.org/books/recovering-biblical-manhood-and-womanhood) - **A Response to Evangelical Feminism by John Piper and Wayne Grudham** - A controversy of major proportions has spread through the church. Recent generations bear witness to the rise of "evangelical feminism"-a movement that has had a profound impact on all of life, challenging some of our basic Christian beliefs...  Combining systematic argumentation with popular application, this volume deals with all of the main passages of Scripture brought forward in this controversy regarding gender-based role differences.  Anyone concerned with the fundamental question of the proper relationship between men and women in home, church, and society will want to read this book.
>
> [50 Crucial Questions About Manhood and Womanhood](https://www.desiringgod.org/books/50-crucial-questions-about-manhood-and-womanhood) - **An Overview of Central Concerns About Manhood and Womanhood by John Piper and Wayne Grudham** - Adapted from chapter two of Recovering Biblical Manhood & Womanhood.
> “This is the booklet I return to most often in dealing with the knotty issues of manhood and womanhood in ministry.”
> “The issue we face in this booklet is how men and women should relate to each other according to the Bible.”

This link is to an article by John Piper on female professors at seminary: [Is There a Place for Female Professors at Seminary?](https://www.desiringgod.org/interviews/is-there-a-place-for-female-professors-at-seminary)

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: I'm positive that the second link (50 Crucial Questions About Manhood and Womanhood) is the one the OP is looking for.

Comment: The 2nd link was it. And it's free!

Comment: @LCIII - Oh,I am pleased, and a free download is even better!